# C# utf8_decoding

Tags: c#, .net, utf8-decode

Equivalent to [utf8_decode in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

I have an string: `"tÃ³picos"` I need convert to `"tópicos"`

How do this?
Thanks,advanced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get the bytes that that string represents in its original encoding (Windows-1252), then read those bytes as UTF8:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetBytes("tÃ³picos" ))
```